# How to see content of specific GTID transaction in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqlbinlog, gtid

To maintain my `GTID-Replication`, I want to see the content of the GTID transaction. I use this command to do that:

```
#I want to see the content of binlog when GTID=1
mysqlbinlog -u USER -p'PASS' mysql-bin.000001  --database=DB  --include-gtids='SERVER_ID:1' --verbose
```

Besides the content, the output contains many strange lines starting with `# at number`. When I add `| wc -l`, those lines exceed thousands.

What I want is:

1. What are those lines? Is there a way to remove them?
2. The output contains many lines starting with #, /* (comments). Is there a way to remove them?

I know it is possible to redirect the output and then use commands like `grep` to remove them; I want to know if there is a utility with `mysqlbinlog` to do that for me.